# Is it possible to download PDF and save to mobile filesystem in React Native using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using Expo and React Native, but can't download PDF file and save it to filesystem.
I don't find any examples and exact answer.

Is it possible to download PDF and then save it to docs?

Answer (score -1):

Your goal can be achieved using `expo-media-library` and `expo-file-system`. Have a try this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

class TestClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    async saveFile() {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        if (status === "granted") {

            FileSystem.downloadAsync("http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf", FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'test.pdf')
            .then( async ({uri}) => {
                await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri)
            }).catch((err) => {
               console.log(err)
            })
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={{flex : 1, justifyContent : 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Button title="Create PDF" onPress={() => this.saveFile()}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
    
}
export default TestClass
```

Comment: catching error prints "This file type is not supported yet"

Comment: This is working fine on Android. However try by changing this way.

Comment: it works for Android smoothly, but not for IOS. Is it possible on IOS? Did you test it?